# remove string from json row

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I'm taking several columns from a data frame and adding them to a new column.

```
A B C
1 3 6
1 2 4 
4 5 0 

df['D'] = df.apply(lambda x: x[['C', 'B']].to_json(), axis=1)
```

I'm then creating a new data frame that locates the unique instances of `df['A']`:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': df.A.unique()})
```

finally, I'm creating a new column in df2 that list the value of `df['B']` and `df['C']`

```
df2['E'] = [list(set(df['D'].loc[df['A'] == x['A']]))
                     for _, x in df2.iterrows()]
```

but this is stringing each object:

```
A B C D
1 3 6 ['{"B":"3","C":6"}', '{"B":"2","C":4"}']
```

furthermore, when I dump this in JSON I get:

```
payload = json.dumps(data)
```

I get this result:

```
["{\"B\":\"3\",\"C\":"6"}", "{\"B\":\"2\",\"C\":"\4"}"]
```

but I'm ultimately looking to remove the string on the objects and have this as the output:

```
[{"B":"3","C":"6"}, {"B":"2","C":"4"}]
```

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case do `groupby` with `to_dict`

```
out = df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x : x[['B','C']].to_dict('records')).to_frame('E').reset_index()
out
Out[198]: 
   A                                     E
0  1  [{'B': 3, 'C': 6}, {'B': 2, 'C': 4}]
1  4                    [{'B': 5, 'C': 0}]
```

Comment: this is the output I'm looking for but how do I name the column of the output? it seems as if df['E'] from my example is being lost but now the column name is '0'